# Biggest number of a field in Json data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

My Json data is as below

```
[{
  "Name": "PieChart",
  "Id": "1",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Name": "Calendar",
  "Id": "2",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Name": "FavouriteFilter",
  "Id": "3",
  "ColumnLocation": "2",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Name": "FilterResults",
  "Id": "4",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "1"
}, {
  "Name": "Watched",
  "Id": "5",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "1"
}]
```

I need to find the highest number of the ColumnLocation of the above data. I need that information because I can draw my dashboard based on this number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map every `ColumnLocation` key and use `Math.max` function to get the highest value.

```js
var data = [{"Name":"PieChart","Id":"1","ColumnLocation":"0","RowLocation":"0"},{"Name":"Calendar","Id":"2","ColumnLocation":"1","RowLocation":"0"},{"Name":"FavouriteFilter","Id":"3","ColumnLocation":"2","RowLocation":"0"},{"Name":"FilterResults","Id":"4","ColumnLocation":"0","RowLocation":"1"},{"Name":"Watched","Id":"5","ColumnLocation":"1","RowLocation":"1"}], 
    res = data.map(v => v.ColumnLocation);
    
    //console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, res));
    console.log(Math.max(...res));
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad I had to use `apply` to be able to use this method on an array. I can do it with just `Math.max` but I will have to use the spread operator, to get the values out of the array.

Comment: I get it now, had a mental lapse. Thanks for the explanation though, perhaps add it your  answer.

Answer (score 4):

Reduce:

```js
const a = [{
  "Name": "PieChart",
  "Id": "1",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Name": "Calendar",
  "Id": "2",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Name": "FavouriteFilter",
  "Id": "3",
  "ColumnLocation": "2",
  "RowLocation": "0"
}, {
  "Name": "FilterResults",
  "Id": "4",
  "ColumnLocation": "0",
  "RowLocation": "1"
}, {
  "Name": "Watched",
  "Id": "5",
  "ColumnLocation": "1",
  "RowLocation": "1"
}];

const r = a.reduce((a, c) => (c.ColumnLocation > a) ? c.ColumnLocation : a, 0);

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Chucking out there a solution using the lodash [**maxBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#maxBy) function:

```
const maxColumnLocation = _.maxBy(data, 'ColumnLocation').ColumnLocation;
```

Comment: `Array.prototype` really needs more methods. I want `maxBy`, `orderBy`, and especially `groupBy`!

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Quite happy to update the answer if you tell me what's wrong

Comment: No idea who downvoted, the question is tagged with `[lodash]` so your answer seems appropriate.